# How to handle exception chaining raised from the except block

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

In my example I have a custom exception class `MyCustomException` and in main I divide an integer `a` by zero which raises a `ZeroDivisionError` exception. With the except block I catch `ZeroDivisionError` and then raise `MyCustomException` from `err`; this creates a chained exception, my own, plus the one in `err`.

Now how can I catch chained exceptions or how do chained exceptions work? Python doen't let me to catch `MyCustomException`  in my code with `except` block.

```
class MyCustomException(Exception):
    pass

a=10
b=0 
reuslt=None

try:
    result=a/b

except ZeroDivisionError as err:
    print("ZeroDivisionError -- ",err)
    raise MyCustomException from err

except MyCustomException as e:
        print("MyException",e)                 # unable to catch MyCustomException
```

The output I get when I execute it:

```
ZeroDivisionError --  division by zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 13, in <module>
MyCustomException
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `raise` in the `except` clause won't search for exception handlers in the same `try` block (*it did not occur in that `try` block*).

It will search for handlers one level up , that is, an outer `try` block. If that isn't found it'll interrupt execution as it normally does (resulting in the exception being displayed).

In short, you need an enclosing `try` in the outer level with the appropriate `except MyCustomException` in order to catch your custom exception:

```
try:
    try:
        result=a/b
    except ZeroDivisionError as err:
        print("ZeroDivisionError -- ",err)
        raise MyCustomException from err

except MyCustomException as e:
    print("Caught MyException", e)
```

Which, when executed, now prints out:

```
ZeroDivisionError --  division by zero
Caught MyException
```